# In R, how do I replace NA value with mean value of group?

Tags: r, replace, na

I have two data frames, the first (`dat`) has two columns `group` and `value`. The second data frame (`dat2`) has the mean value for each `group`. How would I replace the NA values in `dat` with the mean value of the group found in `dat2`?

```
library(dplyr)

x <- as.data.frame(seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1))
names(x)[1] <- "value"
y <- as.data.frame(c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),1)
names(y)[1] <- "group"

dat <- cbind(y,x)

dat[dat == 3] <- NA
dat[dat == 7] <- NA

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_at(.vars = names(.)[2],.funs = c(mean="mean"),na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```r
library(dplyr)

x <- as.data.frame(seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1))
names(x)[1] <- "value"
y <- as.data.frame(c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),1)
names(y)[1] <- "group"

dat <- cbind(y,x)

dat[dat == 3] <- NA
dat[dat == 7] <- NA

dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    value = ifelse(is.na(value), mean(value, na.rm = T), value)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```